# Angular NgForm form.resetForm and form.reset not working with array

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I have simple `ngForm` which was working fine with string input and single select dropdown.
I wanted to added multi-select dropdown which introduces array. 
I am facing a weird issue. When i save/ reset the form i am using `form.formReset()` but i still getting "field required validation" error message and a refresh clears it.

The validation issue got introduced post multi-select. I have tried couple of things but no luck. code below -

```
<form #form="ngForm"
      class="form-horizontal"
      (ngSubmit)="save(form)">
  <inf-modal #modal
             (onHide)="form.resetForm()"
             size="medium">
    <mat-card>
      <mat-card-title class="inf-modal-title">
        Modal View
        <button type="button"
                class="close"
                aria-label="Close"
                (click)="modal.hide()">
          <span aria-hidden="true">
            <mat-icon>clear</mat-icon>
          </span>
        </button>
      </mat-card-title>
      <mat-card-content>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                  <inf-person-org-composite-entity-selector name="autocompleteSelector"
                                                            [(ngModel)]="selectedTarget"
                                                            (ngModelChange)="storeTargetId($event)"
                                                            [blackList]="blacklistedTargets"
                                                            [multiSelect]="false"
                                                            [required]="true"
                                                            [placeholder]="'Name"

                                                            [entitySelectorVisible]="false">
                  </inf-person-org-composite-entity-selector>
                </div>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row"
             *ngIf="!isTargetInvestigation()">
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <inf-multiselect #linkType="ngModel"
                        name="linkType"
                        [(ngModel)]="record.linkType"
                        [optionKey]="'linkType'"
                        [placeholder]="'linkType' "
                        [required]="true"></inf-multiselect>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row"
             *ngIf="!isTargetInvestigation()">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput
                       #comment="ngModel"
                       [(ngModel)]="record.comment"
                       name="comment"
                       [placeholder]="'comment' ">
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </mat-card-content>
      <mat-card-actions>
        <button type="button"
                (click)="modal.hide()"
                mat-button
                color="primary">{{ 'common.cancel' | translate }}
        </button>
        <button type="reset"
                (click)="form.resetForm()"
                mat-button
                color="primary">{{ 'common.reset' | translate }}
        </button>
        <button mat-raised-button
                color="primary"
                type="submit">{{ 'common.assign' | translate}}
        </button>
      </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>
  </inf-modal>
</form>
```

don't know what i am missing, i have even tried playing with pristine and dirty properties of `ngForm`.

[image]

Comment: if ngForm is FormGroup then what you store in "form" itself in (onHide)="form.resetForm()" ?

Comment: @Radik-  just doing a reset as this form is inside a modal.  form is being reset by 2 calls. Top one is on hide clear icon. There is another reset button in bottom

Comment: Use `ReactiveForm` From

Comment: @kiranMistry- ReactiveForm  .. i haven't used them before. But i am still trying to understand does ngFormv validation breaks on multiselect ? i don't think so maybe i am missing something

Comment: @KiranMistry i am using 2 way data binding in the form. The same component is used for create, edit, view

Comment: Hi, I noticed the tag for linkType <inf-multiselect> is not closed with </inf-multiselect> but </inf-select>. Maybe changing that fixes it?

Comment: @zwiers: it was a typo i had corrected it. still the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through a lot of discussions and forums. I would suggest make changes inside the multi-select component maybe check for  reset function inside component or create one and try  adding .markAsPristine() and .markAsUntouched() by checking a condition whenever a reset was clicked on i.e. a blank value was selected.